# Why does `object_id` of symbols vary between rails console and pry/irb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

While I was debugging `BasicObject#method_missing` (I had a `No Id Given` error), I came to the conclusion that the first argument of `rb_method_missing(int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)` is mapped to a method name (with the help of `:symbol.object_id`).

I wanted to check it, so I typed `:symbol.object_id` in rails console (Rails 4.2/Ruby 2.2):

```
:symbol.object_id
# => 771548
```

Then I checked in IRB (Ruby 2.2):

```
:symbol.object_id
# => 771548
```

and everything looked awesome. I tried in IRB:

```
:michał_kulesza.object_id
# => 2531228
```

and then in rails console:

```
:michał_kulesza.object_id
# => 7816668
```

Why does `:symbol` have the same `object_id` in both cases while `:michał_kulesza` has a different one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `:symbol` have the same `object_id` in both cases while `:michał_kulesza` has a different one?

This is because the symbol `:symbol` was already generated (by a gem):

```
$ irb

irb(main):001:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /sym/
#=> [:to_sym, :all_symbols, :symlink?, :symlink, :sym, :symbol, :@post_symbeg]
#                                                      ^^^^^^^

irb(main):002:0> :symbol.object_id
#=> 771548
```

If you start IRB without loading any gems, you get a different result:

```
$ ruby --disable-gems -S irb

irb(main):001:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /sym/
#=> [:to_sym, :all_symbols, :symlink?, :symlink, :@post_symbeg]

irb(main):002:0> :symbol.object_id
#=> 833308
```

Generating another symbol before `:symbol` results in a different object id:

```
$ ruby --disable-gems -S irb

irb(main):001:0> :foo.object_id
#=> 833308

irb(main):002:0> :symbol.object_id
#=> 833628
```

Rails generates many symbols, that's why `:michał_kulesza` has a much higher object id in rails console.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? `object_id`s only have four properties:

- `object_id` is an `Integer`
- every object has an `object_id`
- no two objects have the same `object_id` at the same time (however, note that two different objects may have the same `object_id` at *different* times, i.e. `object_id`s might get re-used)
- an object's `object_id` doesn't change during its lifetime

Your observation doesn't violate any of those four properties, therefore, it is perfectly valid.

There may be some optimization and/or caching going on, so that certain `Symbol`s always have the same `object_id`. Whatever the case, this is purely an internal implementation detail of YARV and *not* a semantic of Ruby.

For example, YARV optimizes `nil`, `false`, `true`, `Fixnum`s (`Integer`s that fit into n-1 bits, where n is the size of a machine word), flonums (`Float`s that fit into n-2 bits, for n >= 64) and certain `Symbol`s, and one side-effect of this is that those objects always have the same `object_id`. However, that is not guaranteed, and for example, when flonums were introduced, the `object_id` of `nil` changed from `4` to `8`.

Comment: So the real question is: Why did `:symbol.object_id` return the same value in  Rails console and IRB (unless it is a coincidence)?

Comment: Some sort of caching optimization, most likely. I haven't kept up with recent developments in YARV, specifically with GC-able `Symbol`s (I find JRuby+Truffle much more interesting), so I can't say definitively. It might *also* be that those Polish `ł`s are encoded differently, and the `object_id` would have been the same had they been encoded identically. Or maybe the caching only works for pure 7-bit ASCII `Symbol`s.